# How to change the icon of a leaflet map by a customized icon

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, leaflet, icons

I've downloaded an imagen that I want to be my marker icon. I saved this image in my asp.net core project path: wwwroot/images/green_icon. Then I write the following code

```
var greenIcon = L.icon({ 
    iconUrl: '~/images/green_icon.png'
});

    L.marker([41.349412, 2.151421], {
        title: 'Martainer',
        id: '1',
        icon: greenIcon
    }).addTo(mymap)
```

My problem is that when  I run the app I see the following error:
GET http://localhost:5000/Home/~/images/green_icon.png 404 (Not Found)

I dont know how to change this path. My image is in my project.
Any help?
Thanks

Comment: As long as you know the URL for the icon image you can substitute it in the `iconURrl` property.

Answer (score 0):

try using `iconUrl: 'images/green_icon.png'` instead.

In my case I am using 'img/mypath.png'

and my project structure is like this
[image]